# Use SAML Authentication from self hosted wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, saml

I want to use SAML authentication in my web application. 
This application is for some reasons not hosted in IIS, but runs as standalone WCF service. Http request are handled within wcf, and all files of the website are returned by wcf

With IIS, i would use the modules WSFederationAuthenticationModule and SessionAuthenticationModule in order to bootstrap the SAML support.

Is it possible to support SAML authentication without IIS?
How can i setup WCF in order to support SAML authentication without IIS?

Comment: you saw this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297476/how-to-integrate-saml-authentication-into-wcf-web-service-application

Answer (score 1):

if you use owin to self-host your wcf service then yes you can. Just look at the examples of setting up saml using owin

http://leastprivilege.com/2013/10/31/adding-saml11-and-saml2-support-to-katanaowin/